# Best way to store images in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to store product images foreach product.
I decided that it is a good way to store images in a folder and save url's for them in database table. 
Now table looks like:

```
ProductId|Name |ImgUrl |
-----------------------
1        |Prod1|SomeUrl|
```

But where shuld I save images?
In Conten/Image folder? 
And how then get the path to this folder?

Comment: how many images? how large? how about security and backup?

Answer (score 2):

You can save it on Content folder, I usually save it on **Content** folder for maintenance so that if some other programmers look for particular images, they can easily check it on **Content** folder:

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/MyImageFolder/")) + "filename.jpg";

file.SaveAs(strPath); //HttpPostedFileBase file
```

To access it you can do this:

```
    string strDirectory = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/MyImageFolder/"));
    string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory);
    string strFileName = string.Empty;
    foreach (var strFile in strFiles)
         {
            strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFile);
          }
```